# Phalcon PhP - how to use $this->acl->isAllowed in .volt view

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm working in a Phalcon 2.0.13 Project using the ACL to control permissions. My Question is: is there a way for me to use the isAllowed in a .volt view?

My goal is to control some options I show in the .volt view based on user's permissions.

Just to clarify to which function I mean:

```
    if( !$this->acl->isAllowed( $userRole, ucfirst( $this->dispatcher->getControllerName() ), $this->dispatcher->getActionName() ) ){
        $this->response->redirect( $this->url->get(['for' => 'admin-index-login']) );

    }
```

This is a piece of code I run inside my base controller, I would like to check for permissions in the .volt view, something like `{{ if isAllowed("User", "New") }} xxxx {{ endif }}`

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should be able to call it like `acl.isAllowed` if you defined `acl` in the DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If acl is added as service then just do:

```
{% if acl.isAllowed("User", "New") %}

{% endif %}
```

No need to custom function in volt. Phalcon ACL Memory based have a lot more options than database and it's faster anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. I will load the acl permissions based on my database and then check like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve. My permission system is in the database, because the admin can set permissions to roles, user groups or a particular user.

1. When the user logs in the system, I keep all his permissions in session
2. Instead of using the acl (I was doing it before) I made a function that checks if the user has permission in the controller/action (My permissions are based on controller and action, like the ACL).
3. I created a custom function to use in the .volt views:

   ```
       $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();

       //Custom volt functions
       $compiler->addFunction('has_permission', function($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
           return '\HelperFunctions::UserHasPermission(' . $resolvedArgs . ')';
       });
   ```

`UserHasPermission` receives the controller and action names to check if the user has permission. I'm using it like this:

```
    {% if has_permission("user", "*") %}

    <li>
        <a href="#" title="Users"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-user"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Users</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url(['for': 'admin-user-index']) }} " title="Users"><span class="menu-item-parent">Users</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    {% endif %}
```

`*` in the action name means if the user has permission in any of the UserController actions.

So far I'm happy with the solution and if at some point I want to switch back to Phalcon's ACL it is pretty easy.